# How to hide window title bar in 20.04?

Tags: 20.04

When window is maximized, I want title bar to be removed. I've installed [`gnome-shell-extension-pixelsaver`](https://github.com/pixel-saver/pixel-saver), but it's not doing anything.

Comment: In which application do you want to remove the title bar?

Comment: @technastic_tc All of them. But at least on Chrome & Jetbrains products would be nice.

Comment: In Chrome, go to Settings → Appearance. Turn off _Use system title bar and borders_.

Comment: @mrSuperEvening JetBrain's Pycharm seems to be working as is with Pixel Saver. @technastic_tc's comment shows how to configure Chrome for its border to be removed when maximized by Pixel Saver. Did you restart GNOME Shell after installing the extension? To restart GNOME Shell press `Alt`+`F2`, input `r` and press `Enter`. Then open Extensions and make sure that Pixel Saver is enabled.

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2015/no-title-bar-forked/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Install [Unite](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/) extension from GNOME extension store and modify its settings according to your need. Remember to restart GNOME shell by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then running `r` command.

It will look like this

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: In 22.04 the ALT+F2 r command doesn't works, but you only need unzip the extension, and enable it on `extensions` icon. Works nice. If you want advanced, out the box alternative, is better using Debian+WMaker, it is a lighter and slim option with full control of your windows.